# How to cast List<T> to specific type

Tags: java

I have the code that looks like the following:

```
public class Option {
    ...
}

public class SpecOption extends Option {
    ...
}

public class Data {
    private List<Option> options;

    public <T extends Option> void setOptions(List<T> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    public <T extends Option> getOptions() {
        return (List<T>) options;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Option option = new Option();
        List<Option> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        lst.add(option);
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setOptions(lst);

        List<SpecOption> spec = data.getOptions(); // I want to get here null or ClassCastException.
        SpecOption = spec.get(0);    // I get ClassCastException here
    }
}
```

how to cast to specific type in the line above `SpecOption = spec.get(0);`?

Comment: If you get a `ClassCastException` then the element returned is not of type `SpecOption`. Hence, it cannot be cast to a `SpecOption`.

Comment: If you want to get a `List<SpecOption>` reference to a `List<Option>` and check that the elements are of the correct type, you would have to iterate through the list and check the type of each element.

Comment: @Turing85 yes, but why do I get a list of the wrong objects? I need to get this exception earlier in the ```getOptions()``` method.

Comment: The generic type is defined wrong then. Casting does nothing else then change the compiler's view. IIRC, the JLS just states that a cast has to be inserted to guarantee types, but the compiler is allowed to insert it wherever it sees fit.

Comment: I would expect an error starting at `this.options = options;`; at least one at `public <T extends Option> getOptions()` - maybe you should work with `Data<T>` (have that class generic, not just the methods)

Comment: If you are getting a `ClassCastException`, then maybe the code that you are running differs from the code you have posted. Because your class `Data` will not compile. Assignment in the `setOptions()` is illegal. And return type is missing in the declaration of `getOptions()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are figment of `javac`'s imagination. It's entirely a compile time show.

The offending line is this one:

> ```java
> public <T extends Option> getOptions() {
>   return (List<T>) options;
> }
> ```

Which is why javac gave you a warning which you evidently decided to ignore (don't do that). generics is something that applies solely to compile time, and the compiler is telling you that it can't verify any of the generics. In other words, now you have no type checking at all. The compiler is telling you: If you ignore this warning, you will get ClassCastExceptions in really bizarre places: Places with zero casts!

It's not entirely clear what you want here, but in broad strokes, you want something like either this:

```
public class Data {
  private List<? extends Option> options;

  public void setOptions(List<? extends Option> options) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  public List<? extends Option> getOptions() {
    return this.options;
  }

  public <T extends Options> List<T> getOptionsAs(Class<T> desiredType) {
    var result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Option o : options) {
      result.add(desiredType.cast(o));
    }
    return result;
}

// and to use:

List<SpecOption> options = opt.getOptionsAs(SpecOption.class);
// The above line throws a ClassCastEx if neccessary.
```

The above has no generics warnings, lets you 'set' options with anything suitable (given a `List<SpecOption>`, you can just pass that to `setOption`, whereas in your code you can't without a warning-causing cast. You don't want those casts. You can read the options, and if you want specifically: Either give me the options specifically as a list of SpecOption objects, or, if there's one or more option objects in there that isn't a SpecOption, throw a ClassCastException right away - then that's what `getOptionsAs` does.

Yes, a loop. As I said, generics is purely a compiler show. If you want type safety you have to program it, which the above example does.

or, perhaps something more along the lines of this:

```
public class Data<T extends Option> {
  private List<? extends T> options;

  public void setOptions(List<? extends T> options) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  public List<? extends T> getOptions() {
    return this.options;
  }
}
```

Here you set up a `Data` object to pre-pick the kind of option type it's supposed to have.